# Natural way to say "brokered volume" and "mediated customers" in a financial context?

Tags: vocabulary

I have a hard time to find the correct and natural English terms for the volume a broker (e. g. for an investment fund) has "contracted". I found some English texts which use "brokered volume", but I noticed that they are solely translations into English and no original texts. Therefore I have been wondering if there is a more natural way to describe that particular kind of "volume" in English? A more dedicated expression than the generic "volume" on it's own?

And how would an English speaker call the "customers" of a broker? The buyers of the commission the broker acts as a broker for, but from the broker's point of view? Is there even a specific English word or would an English speaking broker simply refer to "buyers" when talking about their "customers"?

Comment: I don't know about the first part of your question, but  I think a broker would have **clients**. It would, however, be useful if you provide actual examples of the sentences that use the phrases. Context is everything.

Comment: [Please do not use the simple present like that. You mean: I'm having a hard time etc. ] A broker would say My clients and clients pay him/her a commission. So the commissions earned by a broker. A broker's commissions.